# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

```
    <?php
 // Array com os dias da semana
 $diasemana = array('Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado');

 // Aqui podemos usar a data atual ou qualquer outra data no formato Ano-mês-dia (2014-02-28)
 $data = date('Y-m-d');

 // Varivel que recebe o dia da semana (0 = Domingo, 1 = Segunda ...)
 $diasemana_numero = date('w', strtotime($data));

 // Exibe o dia da semana com o Array
 echo $diasemana[$diasemana_numero];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tem caracteres (quase) invisíveis no seu código ([*em space*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2003/index.htm)), no início de cada linha. Remova os espaços que estão no início de cada linha. Isso com certeza foi causado por ter copiado e colado esse código de algum lugar...

Comment: Que, por sinal, é o caractere [`&#8195;`](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/8195)

Comment: Exatamente, esse mesmo :)